# knockout chaning binding events

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, knockout.js

Currently I am unable to fire off a binding event that is dependent on the results of another binding event in knockout.

In the example below, provide a value in the 'available' input,  when the 'condition1' input is filled with a value such as 22 the 'available' input should be cleared and disabled, all of this is done in the skip logic binding. This is happening properly.

However, the problem lies with the execution of the skiplogic binding on the chain1 input element. This isn't even being fired after the 'available' input is cleared of its value. How can I get it so the results of one binding fires off another binding?

Here is the js fiddle version of the code below: http://jsfiddle.net/gYNb8/2/

Here is the form I am using to test the concept out on:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<span>Condition 1</span> 
<input id="condition1" data-bind="value: condition1" />
<br/>
<span>Condition 2</span> 
<input id="condition2" data-bind="value: condition2" />
<br/>
<span>Available?</span> 
<input id="available" data-bind="value: available, skipLogic: condition1, skipLogic: condition2" />
<br/>
<span>Chain1</span> 
<input id="chain1" data-bind="value: chain1, skiplogic: available" />
```

Here is the javascript:

// Overall viewmodel for this screen, along with initial state
    function ReservationsViewModel() {
        var self = this;

```
    self.condition1 = ko.observable();
    self.condition2 = ko.observable();
    self.available = ko.observable();
    self.chain1 = ko.observable();

}

//Here are the conditions which govern whether an element should be enabled or not
var elementConditions = {
    'available': [{
        'Condition': 'condition1() > 0',
        'Type': 'evaluation'
    }, {
        'Condition': 'condition2() > 0',
        'Type': 'evaluation'
    }],
        'chain1': [{
        'Condition': 'available',
        'Type': 'empty'
    }]
};


ko.bindingHandlers.skipLogic = {
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {


        var id = $(element).attr("id");
        var conditions = elementConditions[id];
        var isSkipped = false;
        var conditionMet = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < conditions.length; i++) {
            conditionMet = false;
            if (conditions[i].Type == "evaluation") {
                conditionMet = eval('viewModel.' + conditions[i].Condition);
            } else if (conditions[i].Type == "empty") {
                if ($('#' + conditions[i].Condition).val().length == 0) {
                    conditionMet = true;
                }
            } else if (conditions[i].Type == "notempty") {
                if ($('#' + conditions[i].Condition).val().length > 0) {
                    conditionMet = true;
                }
            }

            if (conditionMet == true) {
                isSkipped = true;
            }
        }

        if (isSkipped) {
            eval("viewModel." + id + "('');");            
            $(element).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        } else {
            if (elementSkipped[id] > 0) {
                $(element).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else {
                $(element).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        }
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(new ReservationsViewModel());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of trying to keep the conditions separately, can you use Boolean logic to string them together in the binding? this way you don't need to keep track of each bindings state. I have built the following binding:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.skipLogic = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
},
update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    var valueOfCondition = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
    var jqElement = $(element);       

//update if the field is disabled if more than one condition is met        
        if(valueOfCondition){
            jqElement.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else{
            jqElement.prop('disabled', false);
        }
     }
};
```

a working example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/M7vUV/3/

Comment: Note, Knockout is sooo awesome, it will only call this binding when the result of the expression changes values! This is a little fact I learned while writing this feature.

Answer (score 0):

The `update` function for a binding will be executed when the element is first bound (after the `init` function) and then will run again whenever any of its dependencies change.  You create dependencies by accessing observables within the function (like inside of a computed, because a computed is actually used to facilitate the binding updates).

So, you would want to ensure that you are accessing the retrieving whatever you passed to the binding by calling `valueAccessor()`, then if the value is observable you would want to call it as a function to retrieve the value.  Otherwise, if you unsure whether you have been passed an observable you can call `ko.unwrap` (before 2.3 this was `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` - post 2.3 either can be used).

Additionally, you could access values passed to other bindings by using the `allBindingsAccessor` argument (3rd argument) or accessing values directly off of the data (4th arg) or context (5th arg).

It will not work to pass multiple bindings with the same name of the same element.  You might want to consider structuring it differently like passing an array `data-bind="skipLogic: [one, two]"` and then accessing the values off of each.

Comment: Could you be a little more detailed? Why is skiplogic: available  on the 'chain1' input not being triggered when the 'available' input is cleared by this section of code:

     if (isSkipped) {
                eval("viewModel." + id + "('');");            
                $(element).attr("disabled", "disabled");
            } else {
                if (elementSkipped[id] > 0) {
                    $(element).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } else {
                    $(element).removeAttr("disabled");
                }
            }

Comment: There are a couple of issues at play here. First you have specified `skiplogic` instead of `skipLogic` on the `chain1` element. Bindings are case sensitive. Second for the `empty` and `notempty` conditions, you will want to access the observable's value to create a dependency. So, rather than reading the value off of the field, perhaps something like: `viewModel[conditions[i].Condition]()`. This syntax will let you dynamically specify the property name to access without doing something like an eval. Additionally, you have an elementSkipped variable that is undefined.

Comment: Here is a fiddle with just these things fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/4jbb5/. Overall, I think that it might be a better situation to put this logic in your view model using computed observables and then use normal bindings against the elements  (to enable/disable the element).

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. Could you provide where you found the documentation on creating a value dependency by using viewModel[conditions[i].Condition]()?

Comment: This is using bracket notation to access a property. This link may help provide some information for you: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.  So, you can access an object's members like `viewModel.blah` or `viewModel['blah']`. In this case since we have a dynamic string, the bracket notation gives us access to the property that we want and calling it as a function (it is an observable) gives us back the value which also creates a dependency. Hope that helps.

Comment: I still don't understand. I get how you can call it as a property which is how objects normally work in javascript.  But the equivalent of viewModel[criteria[i].Condition]() at one instance can be viewModel['viewModel.condition2() > 0']() in the case of the binding on the 'available' input or even viewModel['available']() in the case of the 'chain1' input. 

How does viewModel['viewModel.condition2() > 0']() or viewModel['available']()  result in a dependency (really a delegate) and is called with the fields referenced in it as they are updated?

Comment: In the example, I only used that syntax for the empty/notempty ones that only contain strings.